# Як краще перекласти "advanced level"? Просунутий чи високий рівень?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Цікавить переклад словосполучення "[advanced level](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/advanced-level)" (офіційна назва одного з рівнів володіння англійською мовою). Пошуки в Інтернеті не дали багато інфомрації. [Гугл перекладач](https://translate.google.cn/?hl=ru#en/uk/advanced%20level) пропонує перекласти як "просунутий рівень", однак мій викладач з університету запропонував переклад "високий рівень".

Однак, якщо заглянути в СУМ, то можна побачити, що в слова "[просунитий](http://sum.in.ua/s/prosunutyj)" немає потрібного значення. Однак, мені вдалося знайти [приклад](http://www.univ.kiev.ua/ua/resources/tests4/) вживання словосполучення "просунутий рівень":

> Згідно із Загальноєвропейськими Рекомендаціями з мовної освіти існує
>   шість рівнів володіння мовою, які були розроблені Асоціацією Мовних
>   Експертів ALTE (The Association of Language Testers in Europe):
>   інтродуктивний (Breakthrough або А1), середній (Waystage або А2),
>   рубіжний (Threshold або В1), **просунутий** (Vantage або В2), автономний
>   (Effective Operational Proficiency або С1) і компетентний (Mastery або
>   С2).

А от слово "[високий](http://sum.in.ua/s/vysokyj)" в СУМі має таке значення: "Який має рівень, більший від звичайного", а також: "Дуже добрий, відмінний, розвинений". Проте, мені  не вдалося знайти інформації про "високий рівень" володіння мовою.

Тому не знаю як краще перекласти це словосполучення, довіритися Гуглові та онлайн ресурсам чи викладачеві? Чи може можна вживати і один і другий варіанти для перекладу.

Comment: Саме для вашого запитання ПРОСУНУТИЙ РІВЕНЬ буде найкращим українським відповідніком. Але пам'ятаємо, що переклад завжді здійснюється відповідно до контексту.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Гадаю, що *високий рівень* міг би бути хорошим перекладом в художньому творі, але коли мова йде про документацію і стале словосполучення, яке у багатьох на слуху, то варто віддати перевагу більш дослівному перекладу, щоб читачу було одразу зрозуміло про що йдеться. Зрештою в інших ситуаціях, з великою ймовірністю, ми можемо зустріти і *high level* і *perfect level*, а відповідний дослівний переклад вже буде зайнятий. Тому, я вважаю, що переклад *просунутий рівень* підходить найкраще.

Comment: "...в художньому творі..." в реальному житті склалося навпаки =)

Answer (score 2):

Переклад по змісту:
Advanced Restaurant Leader — старший керівник.

[Старший](https://sum11.com.ua/starshyj-2/)

> СТА́РШИЙ, а, е.
> 3. Який стоїть вище за званням, посадою, чином, службовим становищем у порівнянні з ким-небудь.

> Вищий за владою, значенням, важливістю.

Наприклад, старша медсестра.

Advanced level — вищий ступінь.

[Ступінь](https://sum11.com.ua/stupinj/)

> СТУ́ПІНЬ, пеня, чол.
>
> 1. Порівняльна величина, що характеризує розмір, інтенсивність чого-небудь.

> ▲ Вищий ступінь див. вищий; Звичайний ступінь
> див. звичайний; Ступені порівняння див. порівняння 1.

Наприклад, Advanced Calculus — це вища математика.

Comment: Старша медсестра - це керівна адміністративна посада з підвищеним рівнем відповідальності, тому англійською буде "Senior Nurse".

Comment: Вища математика - це "Higher Math" або "Higher Mathematics".  Advanced level - тут, краще "поглиблений рівень". Advanced Calculus - тут, краще перекладати як "розширені обчислення". 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_on_Euclidean_space

Comment: А старші класи у них high school, то придумаємо вищу школу,  чи будемо думати як українці? Бо ми таки не американці і думаємо інакше, і слова вживаємо інші. Ваш текст буде читати українець, який вищу школу зовсім не зрозуміє, бо він усе життя знав старші класи. То ж безглуздо перекладати для американців, а треба для українців, щоби вони розуміли, що там пишеться.

Comment: Roman Mikhol а що нам до них? У них наше слово коса перекладається купою слів. І під кожне їхнє ми маємо придумати нове власне? З якого дива? У нас є свої слова, які мають властиві нам значення і ми маємо користуватися українською мовою, а не англійською в українських словах. Хай вони думають так, а ми думаємо так. Тому ми українці, а вони англійці чи американці.

Comment: Не зовсім розумію до якого саме з моїх аргументів ви апелюєте? Адже вони стосуються саме дисципліни "математика". High School - це "старші класи" або "старша школа", тут жодних заперечень. Higher Education - "вища освіта".

Comment: Я б сказав, що _advanced calculus_ — це радще [математичний аналіз](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Математичний_аналіз), ніж уся _вища математика_. Але загалом з відповіддю згоден (що _advanced_ у назвах професій часто відповідає нашому _старший_, а _advanced_ стосовно рівня — нашому _вищий_).

Comment: Згоден, що матан. Дослівно calculus — це каміння. «Передове каміння» доведе до сказу кожного, хто це читатиме. Треба розуміти, що ми по різному думаємо. Латиняни мали у абаці камінці, як одиницю рахунку. Ми рахували паличками чи кроками (ступінь). Ми теж не маємо свого відповідника, бо «Rachen» німецьке слово. Але навіть вищі чи складні розрахунки ми не використовуємо, бо маємо власні сталі терміни. У питаннях рівнів чи ступенів ми теж давно маємо сталі терміни. Нижчий, середній, вищий. Або поганий, середній, добрий, найкращий. Предки були не дурні — основу дали. Далі користуйтеся.

Answer (score 1):

**Advanced level** - дослівно **Передовий рівень**

[Advance](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/advance) - Move **forward** in a purposeful way. Done, sent, or supplied **beforehand**.

Origin

Middle English from Old French avance (noun), avancer (verb), from late Latin abante ‘**in front**’, from ab ‘from’ + ante ‘before’. The initial a- was erroneously assimilated to ad- in the 16th century.

[**Advanced**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/advanced) - **Far on** or **ahead** in development or progress.

[**Advanced level**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/advanced_level) - fuller form of A level

[**A level**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/a_level) - (in the UK except Scotland) a qualification in a specific subject typically taken by school students aged 16–18, at a level above GCSE. The equivalent in Scotland is the Higher.
Compare with GCSE, O level.

[**Advanced English**](https://tracktest.eu/english-levels-cefr/) - Can understand a wide range of demanding, longer texts, and recognise implicit meaning. Can express him/herself fluently and spontaneously without much obvious searching for expressions. Can use language flexibly and effectively for social, academic and professional purposes. Can produce clear, well-structured, detailed text on complex subjects, showing a controlled use of organisational patterns, connectors and cohesive devices.

[Передовий](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html?wrd=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9) - Який перебуває, діє попереду. Вищий від інших рівнем свого розвитку.

[**Рівень вільного володіння** першого ступеня (C1)](https://mova.gov.ua/news/rivni-volodinnya-derzhavnoyu-movoyu) - український відповідник, який можна використовувати.

Від себе на основі дослідження: знаходиться в перших рядах знання та вільного використання мови, але ще не експерт в усіх питаннях.

Comment: Незрозуміло як ці джерела підтримують вашу версію. якщо в них є щось, що нам важливо знати, то варто це скопіювати сюди.

Comment: Теж не бачу як джерела підтрумують вашу думку.

Answer (score 0):

Я пропоную перекладати *заавансований*. Саме так це слово вживають поляки: *zaawansowany poziom*.

> [Лексикон львівський](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53399/1062410.html)
>
> **аавансований**, **заавансований**
>
> 1. який триває від якогось часу, перебуває не в початковій стадії розвитку; обізнаний *(ст)*,
>
> 4. досвідчений, вправний *(ст)*: *Сюди приходили студенти зі своїми дівчатами, бо місце було близько до університету і відповідно погано освітлене, так що можна було навіть робити деякі заавансовані рухи рук дівчині під столом, і ніхто цього не бачив, а навіть як бачив, то не звертав уваги, бо самий був зайнятий тією самою роботою* (Тарнавський З.).

Comment: Цікаво… Дійсно, [є таке діалектне слово з доречними значеннями](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53399/1062410.html). Щоправда [в загальноукраїнській літературній мові значення цього слова зовсім інше](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=216680&page=918).

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Хоча цей допис, теоретично, може містити відповідь, було б набагато краще, якби він містив обґрунтування на основі посилань на авторитетні джерела та/або академічні дослідження. Дописи, що не містять обґрунтування, часто спричиняють «мінусування» та диспути.

Comment: Добрий день. Підтримую дописувачів вище. Ви завжди можете натиснути на Edit і додати щонайменше якісь посилання, які підтверджують слушність вашої думки.

Answer (score 0):

## Advanced Level

**Advance** в прямому значенні перекладається як **зазадалегідь**, **рухатись уперед**.

**Advance career** перекл. **рухати кар'єру**, **просуватися кар'єрними щаблями**.

---

Переклад "**Advanced**" може бути варіативним і залежатиме від контексту,  в загальному випадку буде означати **"кращий, з посеред рівних"**.

**Level** - **рівень**, **ступінь**, **щабель**, **сходинка**.

**Advanced Level** - **"вищий рівень"**, **"підвищений рівень"**, **"покращений рівень"**, **"просунутий рівень"**, **"поглиблений рівень"**, **"вдосконалений рівень"**.

---

**Advanced Level English**

**The Common European Framework of Reference for Languages ([CEFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages))** — це міжнародний стандарт опису мовних здібностей. Екзаменаційний тест CERF вимірює рівень володіння мовою за шестибальною шкалою від A1 для початківців до C2 для тих, хто її опанував, і, зокрема використовує такі **CEFR Level**:

> **Pre-advanced (C1)**  Я добре говорю і розумію, але все одно роблю помилки. Іноді люди не розуміють мене чітко.
>
> **Advanced (C2)** Я дуже добре говорю та розумію, але іноді маю проблеми з незнайомими ситуаціями та словниковим запасом.
>
> **Very Advanced (C2)** Я вільно розмовляю та розумію англійську мову.

Тому, якщо мова йде про рівень кваліфікації відповідно до результатів тесту, краще сказати **"просунутий рівень С2"**. Якщо казати про рівень володіння без результатів тесту, **"високий рівень"** є цілком нормальним і не слід вважати за помилку.

---

У прикладі з "**Advanced Restaurant Leader**" воно вживається на означення грейду посади, тому доречний переклад, на мою думку, буде такий:

**Провідний менеджер ресторану** / **Провідний лідер ресторану**

Comment: − < тому доречний переклад, на мою думку > Це більше схоже на комент.

Comment: У назві професії слово _провідний_ доречно (щось типу _leading engineer_ — _провідний інженер_). Але ж питання було про словосполучення _advanced level_ у контексті рівня володіння мовою.

Comment: @Sútnôstj, так це був скорше коментар до прикладу одного з дописувачів. Та ви стимулювали мене його розширити :)

Comment: А й справді, серед відповідей було прохання користувачки Abastasia допомогти з перекладом назви посади Advanced Restaurant Leader у МакДональдз. Тож тепер я розумію, звідки пішла тема про advanced у назвах професій/посад. Але те прохання я вилучив, бо неправильно писати запитання у відповідях. Як гадаєте, чи варто тепер створити окреме запитання про переклад advanced у контексті назв професій? Чи хай усе буде тут? (Але тоді, мабуть, варто буде попросити Анатолія (автора запитання) розширити це запитання.)

Comment: Згоден, писати запитання у відповідях це не правильно. Та загалом, воно не суперечить запитанню топікстартера, а тільки розширює можливості з надання прикладів вжитку. Тому, зважаючи що користувач не надто досвідчений і скільки часу піде на створення окремого топіку не зрозуміло, вирішив надати відповідь. Зачекаю деякий час, якщо ваше рішення остаточне, відредагую свою відповідь.

Answer (score -1):

В українській мові є три ступені знання.  Початковий (нижчий), середній і вищий. І три проміжні. Вище початкового, вище середнього та найвищий. Інших рівнів чи ступенів я не знаю. Особливо просунутого. Завжди хочеться спитати — хто, кого/що та куди сунув? Тато сина в міністерство за долари? Бо вищий то зрозуміло, зрозуміло старший, зрозуміло передовий, навіть провідний (провідник — той, що веде за собою, в англійській лідер, в німецькій фюрер а у росіян вождь). Але не просунутий, бо це ще одне одоробло на кшталт «за замовчуванням», яке теж дике, бо ми замовчуємо те, що не хочемо сказати, а не те, що всім відоме і *звичне*, тож і є не за замовчуванням, а звичайним.